# Thoughts of mobile design, where search input at bottom static navbar?

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, e-commerce, mobile-web

How do you guys feel maybe taking a slice of how starbucks does their PWA design and applying it to ecommerce?

Long story short, I am designing an ecommerce site mobile first; and I've come up with the conundrum where to put the search bar. First I thought why not attach at the top like most apps, but I feel like that didn't fit the style and design we are going for. I am experimenting putting it actually at the bottom and keeping the cart button there too. I feel like its more accessible. But at the same time could lead to misclicks [image: starbucks image] [image: my app screenshot]

Let me know what you guys think or have thought of?

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is : Test, test, test!

However, as a standard, both Apple's and Material's guidelines recommend the search bar be on top, and this is what most users will expect.